# How many past month can i get data from youtube api?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

How far can you get data from youtube api? I was testing on getting data from the past and was only able to get 6 months from now. Can anyone confirm  this? Thank you very much

Edit: It seems like the issue is only visible when i'm using the https://github.com/alaouy/youtube package. I tried to access it via url and I got a response data.

EDIT 2:
Here is the call:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={KEY}&part=snippet&channelId=UCBJycsmduvYEL83R_U4JriQ&type=video&order=date&publishedBefore=2016-11-30T23%3A59%3A59.999999%2B08%3A00&publishedAfter=2016-09-01T00%3A00%3A00.000000%2B08%3A00&maxResults=50

I used this script in curl on loop with -3 months every loop in 5 seconds interval

Comment: Can you provide what specific Youtube API call?

Comment: There is no limit. You are perhaps confusing this with the 500 soft limit for query results. Let's see your call.

Comment: Hi @johnh10, I am aware of the 500 soft limit. I successfully get 500 items when the date of the query is for example today. however, when i try to get it from for example start of the year, I can only retrieve around 100-150 items (forgot the exact). If I get the videos from for example 6 months and beyong, no result display.

Comment: Hi @jess, I am using the search list API latest version

Comment: Again, we want to see your exact call.

Comment: @johnh10, I added the exact call in the description. Is there a restriction on youtube api when using it in curl?

Comment: I guess I don't understand the issue. I entered your API call and received 39 results. If you're not getting any results at all, I would check the credentials of your API key for any restrictions.